# How to quantify similarity of tree models? (XGB, Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, etc.)

Tags: classification, regression, random-forest, boosting

Are there any algorithms that quantify the similarity of tree based models such as XGB? For example, I train two XGB models with different datasets for example in cross validation and want to estimate the robustness or consistency of the predictions and maybe how features are used.